# equivalent of MATLAB function gaminv()

Tags: r, matlab, statistics, probability, gamma-distribution

I have been struggling for quite a while trying to find an R equivalent to MATLAB's `gaminv` function.  To my knowledge, there are no packages/functions in R that do exactly what `gaminv does.  I am not sure how to code it up myself either.  Any guidance/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to give us a [link to the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gaminv.html):

> x = gaminv(p,a,b) returns the icdf [inverse cumulative distribution function] of the gamma distribution with shape parameter a and the scale parameter b, evaluated at the values in p.

The inverse cumulative distribution function is also called the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function): these functions are denoted as `q<distname>` in R.  In particular, `qgamma` is the quantile function of the Gamma distribution: the definition from `?qgamma` states

> qgamma(p, shape, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate, lower.tail = TRUE,
>               log.p = FALSE)

In particular, be careful that the R function is parameterized with the rate by default: if you specify `qgamma(0.5, shape=2, 2)` you'll get the value of the function with rate 2 (scale 1/2).  If you want the scale parameterization you need `qgamma(0.5, shape=2, scale=2)`.

I've confirmed using an arbitrary example that `gaminv(0.5,2,2)` (in Octave, since I don't have Matlab) gives the same answer as `qgamma(0.5,2,scale=2)`.

Comment: Ben, thank you so much!  It worked!  And apologies for not providing a link to the documentation.  Quick note: I think you meant qgamma(0.5,2,scale=2) not gamma(0.5,2,scale=2) in the last parapgraph.  Thanks again!

Comment: no problem, just a suggestion for future questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can try start with the [inverse cumulative function](https://rdrr.io/cran/lestat/man/invcdf.html),if this is not exactly what you are looking for, I suggest studying the entire theoretical basis of cumulative inversion and trying to apply it in a non-functional language first, then integrate it into R, or simply read what is written in the original MatLab function and try to reproduce in the R